# <Mac> Ways to annotate screen capture without saving to local

Tags: macos, mac, screen-capture

I would like to ask if there is any way to perform screen capture on mac, perform annotation on it, and then save to clipboard only, without saving to the mac.

I am using "cmd + shift + 5" to get the screenshot. If I choose to save to clipboard, I cannot perform annotation; If I choose to save to disk (say desktop), then I am given the choice to perform annotation, but it can only save to disk after annotating. As I just need to paste the modifed image somewhere, it is kind of troublesome to keep delete the image on disk. Kindly see if there is any advice, thank you very much.

MacOS version: 10.15.5

Comment: This drives me crazy. It's a productivity tool, that's needlessly onerous. The share context (top right in mac windows) could handle this. But the share context in Mac sucks as well. All I want to do is copy/share what I see after making the annotation. My workaround is to take a new screenshot of my old annotated screenshot. Then you can paste that in gmail or webchat or wherever. I haven't posted as a solution because the workaround also sucks, since it sprays files all over your desktop.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. my workaround is to take a screen capture to file, make annotations and then take another scren capture to the clipboard, paste where i need it and delete the first screen